# How to install specific version of yarn using the npm API

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I want to download a specific version of yarn by using the [npm api](https://registry.npmjs.org)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @StevenGoodman Not really, I don't want to use npm install but really some curl on the npm ap to downoad the yarn package i or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the [NPM Registry API](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md), it looks like it would be pretty simple to do that.

`GET: https://registry.npmjs.org/<package>` returns a JSON object with a `versions` field and for each version there is a `dist` field which has a URL to that package's tarball.

If you know the version ahead of time, `GET: https://registry.npmjs.org/<package>/<version>` would also work.

If you just want the tarball straight up, the format for the URL for getting a package's tarball is `https://registry.npmjs.org/<name>/-/<name>-<version>.tgz`. Although the registry documentation says that this might not always be true.